# Mapbox GL JS: Some coordinates are not rendered

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm processing a multi-polygon geojson, but some polygons are not rendered with mapbox-gl-js, generating some gaps. The use of mapbox-js features renders correctly.
This problem only occurs with the mapbox-gl-js API.
This problem also occurs in Mapbox Studio when rederizing a tileset in a style even though the polygon exists in the dataset.

That's the link to the geojson: 
[geojson](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c3a18748ce58ce4fef184c5d2b47361a20190923121902/14888b)

This is the code snippet where I add the layer, with mapbox-gl-js:

```
map.addSource( < id > , {
 type: 'vector',
 url: < url >
});
map.addLayer({
 "id": < id > ,
 "type": "fill",
 "source": < id > ,
 "source-layer": < id > ,
 "layout": {},
 "paint": {
  "fill-color": ["interpolate", ["linear"],
   ["get", "title"], 0.00, "red", 0.30, "#8aac75", 0.60, "#00e6e6", 0.90, "#00c0cc", 1.20, "#00a5cc", 1.50, "#007fcc", 1.80, "#000066", 2.10, "#0018cc", 2.40, "#0000ba", 2.70, "#000099", 3.00, "#000076", 3.30, "#000066", 3.60, "purple"
  ]
 }
}, < layerId > );
```

This is the code snippet where I add the layer, with mapbox-js:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(tmap);
featureLayer.loadURL('/geojson');
```

Would anyone know what may be generating this error?

Comment: These are the results:

[mapbox-js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zrbjQfbXu8LBXDCa__iWGRajlACic6ri)

[mapbox-gl-js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iOv5Bt8dhWPmgasd5VDJhSk3XeQD2SPX)

Comment: Can you share some of your code with us?

Comment: Updated with code.